# Pip error installing PyObjC-core on mac OS 10.13.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyobjc

Hi currently i had PyObjC-core as one of the dependencies in my requirements.txt file, when i try to run

> pip install -r requirements.txt

it return the following error:

```
Collecting pyobjc-core==6.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/80/0cdb2130b86a984e4765beb93135aa9c2120fd64be1a27e1c7cb31c719bc/pyobjc-core-6.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vj52r5i1/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vj52r5i1/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-vj52r5i1/pyobjc-core/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vj52r5i1/pyobjc-core/
    Complete output (2 lines):
    running egg_info
    error: PyObjC requires macOS to build
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I looked for solutions online but still haven't found any answers.

my pip version is 20.0.2 and running on python 3.7

I also had tried with manual install `pip install pyobjc-core` but still no luck

Comment: what does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.platform)"` return when run from your terminal?

Comment: oh it return `linux`, forgot i ran it in docker-container which use linux. Are there any version of pytobjC that can run on linux ?

Comment: I guess not. From the [docs](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):`PyObjC only supports macOS and does not support other platform (iOS, Linux, …)`

Comment: aww that sad to know i guess this problem is resolved, thank you

Comment: Add platform specification to your `requirements.txt`: `pyobjc-core; platform_system=="Darwin"`. See an example at https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/9c9569bf0b0b20a099abef228e1b90a800cd9c07/setup.py#L26

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned also here https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/381, I believe currently the only solution is installing an older release of pyautogui: 
https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/0.9.50/#history.

For instance: pip3 install PyAutoGUI==0.9.48

Comment: still doesn't work, macos will continue to take the wrong pyobjc-core (e.g. 8.3 for me)

Answer (score 0):

I came here with a slightly different error when trying to pip install pyobjc-core latest (8.1) on MacOS 10.15.7.  If you are seeing the following compilation error from gcc ...

```
Modules/objc/OC_PythonNumber.m:553:39: error: unused parameter 'zone' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
```

... then I would refer you to [this issue] on github [1](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issues/412)